# How long is this memory section specified in this .dtb file?

Tags: qemu, riscv, device-tree

I feel like I'm not understanding how to interpret the format of `dtb`/`dts` files, and was hoping you could help.  After running these commands:

```
qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -machine dumpdtb=riscv64-virt.dtb
dtc -I dtb -O dts -o riscv-virt.dts riscv-virt.dtb
```

The resulting `riscv-virt.dts` contains the definition of the `memory` for the machine:

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
    #address-cells = <0x02>;
    #size-cells = <0x02>;
    compatible = "riscv-virtio";
    model = "riscv-virtio,qemu";

    ...other memory definitions...

    memory@80000000 {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x0 0x80000000 0x0 0x8000000>;
    };
};
```

I have a few questions:

1. Why are there multiple pairs of reg definitions?  Based on [this link](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-msm-hammerhead-3.4-kk-r1/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/memory.txt), it appears the second `0x0 0x8000000` overwrites what was just set in the previous pair, `0x0 0x80000000`.
2. How long is this memory bank?  Which value tells me this?
3. The first line says `memory@80000000`, but then the reg commands start at `0x0`.  Does the memory start at `0x0` or `0x80000000`?

Basically, I just feel like I don't understand how to interpret this.  In plain English, what is being defined here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [dts-specification](https://www.devicetree.org/downloads/devicetree-specification-v0.1-20160524.pdf) p. 13 u can read it partially. Reg is given in (address,length) pairs. In your case address and length are given in 64 byte, which is done by using **2!** 32-bit values.
Thus the address is 0x80000000, and the size 0x8000000

Edit:
The variables #address-cells and #size-cells specify how many cells (32-bit values) are used for either address and size. In an original *dts* it is always specified within the device's mother node. Maybe you can find it within your decompiled dts

Comment: I just updated my question to include the top-level `#address-cells` and `#size-cells` after reading your answer.  Your answer makes sense to me, thanks!